# Override equality for Python class attribute?

Tags: python, oop, properties, overriding

I am trying to figure how support of overriding equality on the level of class attributes (not just the class) is implemented in Python.

Say I have a fictional Python class:

```
class Table(object):
    """Table object"""

    def __init__(self,path):
        self.schema = {0:'Name',1:'Name1'}

tbl = Table(r'\\data\path')
tbl.schema
```

`>>> {0: 'Name', 1: 'Name1'}`

The class instance will be created based on the path to a DB table and I want to create a schema property for this class which will store the "order" of fields and their names.

I know that I can check the class attribute equality with just

`tbl.schema == tbl1.schema`

But what if I want to check that the schemas are the same without considering the order of fields?

I could create another property `schema_no_order` and store just the `set` of `{'Name', 1: 'Name1'}` there to be able to check the equality of `schema_no_order` property of two tables. This implies having two properties storing almost the same info.

I think there should be a more elegant solution to this.

**Is it possible to overwrite the equality check specifically for the class attribute, not the class itself?**

So instead of as we do on classes

```
def __eq__(self, other): 
    return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
```

something similar but specific to a certain property equality check:

```
def __eq__prop_name__(self,other,prop_name): 
    return set(self.schema.values()) == set(other.schema.values())
```

So schemas of tables with the same field names in a different order would be considered "equal" in this particular case.

`tbl.schema == tbl1.schema`

`{0: 'Name', 1: 'Name1'} == {2: 'Name', 3: 'Name1'}`

Comment: How about just create a `Schema` class and create the attribute like `self.schema = Schema({0: 'Name', 1: 'Name1'})`?

Comment: Aha, I see, and then do the usual `def __eq__(self, other): ` check on Schema classes, right? Would be cool though if I wouldn't need to create another class for that, do you know if the behavior I tried to describe above is built-in?

Comment: Right. Python doesn't have any kind of `__eq__prop_name__`, and I don't think it will be introduced in the future since it complicates understanding of code without much benefits (i.e. now the meaning of `p.q.r.s == x.y.z` depends not only on the type of the values but also its owners!).

Comment: The schema's equality check is the responsibility of the schema, not your object. It'd be confusing as hell if dict equality worked differently just because the dicts came out of an attribute of your class. Personally, I'd write a helper method for unordered dict equality and use that instead of trying to make `==` work.

Comment: OK, cool thanks. Let's see if someone has other helpful thoughts on that, otherwise feel free to post the idea with the new class as an answer, I'll accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: @user2357112, ah you mean something like `tbl.compare_schema(tbl1)` that will work with the schemas behind the scenes?

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: Something like that, or a function that just takes the two schema objects.

Comment: Ah, OK, cool, thanks a ton. Was reading a book on Python classes and was wondering if this is implemented in some way. Now I realize why this wouldn't be a good idea; writing a method for this is something I'd probably use in the future when needed.